# Rotation glitch Unreal Engine 4

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine4

There's problem, I decided to make an item and player.

[Item's blueprint photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXYDr.png)

When player takes the item item's location goes to ItemPosition's location. I did the same with rotation, but between 180 and -180 degrees there glitch happens, you can see it [here](https://youtu.be/NcEgbmVuemI?si=hh-B8UkzfZyJKvRR&t=4). How to fix this?

I tried to put the `AddActorWorldRotation` insted of `SetActorRotation`. The details are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr8QU.png). But it's very complicated.